# Is there a generic way to cast a current User to one of its roles e.g. Admin?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a `userid` field in token and having custom `IWebContext` instead of just create typical `CurrentUser` inside of it (which does typical get-user-by-id stuff inside of it) I would like to have something like `CurrentUserAsRole<Admin>` which will try to get `Admin` instance by `userId` in case the current user has this role otherwise return `null`.

I've already tried creating a generic extension method for WebContext but stuck with switch-case across varieties of `T` (`where T: User`)
e.g. `(Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T)) == Admin)`

as well as returning instance of `Admin` despite the fact `Admin` is directly nested from `User`

```
public T GetCurrentUserAsRole<T>(int currentUserId) where T: User
{
    switch (Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T)))
    {
        // `Admin` is a type which is not walid in the current context
        case Admin:
            //cannot return Admin as T
            return (T)_adminService.GetByUserId(currentUserId);
    }
}
```

Are there any chance to use _context.GetCurrentUserAsRole(int userId)

Comment: If that's the usual `User` object, a) it's an `IPrincipal` and cannot be casted like that, and b) a user can have multiple roles, so the premise is incorrect anyway. You can use `.IsInRole()` if it helps...

Comment: @sellotape, in case of multiple roles it would be great to have an option get `null` for absent roles or `T` for present ones.

Definitely, `.IsInRole()` would help to avoid unnecessary DB requests, but the general question how to implement `T GetCurrentUserAsRole<T>(int currentUserId)` leaves unsolved. :(

Comment: `User` is of type `ClaimsPrincipal` (the `HttpContext` one in Core is, anyway).  It isn't sealed, so technically you could inherit from that and create `Admin` etc. classes, that you could cast to (with some fiddling), but I'm not sure that's of much benefit.  You will still have to decide what to do if a User has e.g. both the Admin and SuperUser roles.  Perhaps you could explain more what you're trying to achieve, because what you're trying to do is fairly unconventional.

Comment: @sellotape sorry about misleading you. `User` in my case is an instance is the EF.Core entity, with common properties for all other classes for roles, e.g. `Admin` specified above.

Comment: In that case it should be easier?  `Admin` (and other types you want to cast to) must inherit from `User` though.  Also your switch can be (C#7+) `switch (typeof(T)) { case Admin admin: /* ... */ break; case Other other: /* ... */ break; }`